# iPhone Orientation change frame of view

Tags: iphone

I want to set position of UILable programatically depend on orientation. But When I get back to Portrait, it doesn't work.

Here is my code :

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    if([[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation] == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation] == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
    {
        lblUserName.frame = CGRectMake(20, 200, 280, 44); 
        lblPassword.frame = CGRectMake(20, 246, 280, 44); 
    }

    else
    {
        lblUserName.frame = CGRectMake(20, 220, 280, 44); 
        lblPassword.frame = CGRectMake(20, 266, 280, 44); 
    }
}
```

Comment: I also used toOrienation to check current orientation

Comment: You are calling the statusBarOrientation method too early, the device has not rotated yet so statusBarOrientation will return the rotation that you are rotating from

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are  2 possibilities.Either you can set the label programatically.And check the condition for orientation in the - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation{}

method.Otherwise you can use auto resizing mask.

Answer (score 1):

try with this IF condition:

```
 if ( UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(toInterfaceOrientation))
 { 

 } 
 else {}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
//write code here
return YES;
}

- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
{
//write code here
}
```

Use this two methods for set your label when rotate device.